# How do I know if the procfile commands are running on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, prisma

I'm setting up a new REST API in Node and running it on Heroku. I'm using Postgres and Prisma.
I need Heroku to run my db migrations on start in case something changed in my schema.

For that I created a Procfile with the following commands:

```
run: npx prisma generate
run: npx prisma db push
```

If I run those commands in the Heroku console they work and the changes impact the database. What I don't know is how to verify that the Procfile commands were actually run. When I start my application I get these logs:

```
2023-08-21T14:50:19.185922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-08-21T14:50:22.025861+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-08-21T14:50:22.025890+00:00 app[web.1]: > qualis_api@1.0.0 start
2023-08-21T14:50:22.025890+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2023-08-21T14:50:22.025890+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-08-21T14:50:22.512882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-08-21T14:50:22.379409+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 43532
```

I was expecting seeing `npx prisma generate` and `npx prisma db push` on those logs somewhere.

Am I missing something? Are the commands running but not logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Procfile`s

That's not how `Procfile`s work. They aren't for listing commands to run one after the next, they're for [defining process types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format).

[Only two process types —`web` and `release`—are meaningful to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#other-process-types). All others, including `run` as you're using here, are arbitrary names that don't do anything unless you spin up dynos to handle inbound HTTP requests, run them manually, etc.

You could run your command¹ in a one-off dyno manually:

```bash
heroku run run  # the first `run` is a Heroku CLI command,
                # the second is the name of your process
```

But the whole point of your question is how to run these commands *automatically*, not manually.

### Release phase

Instead, you should declare a `release` process type:

```
release: npx prisma db push
```

The release command runs after a successful deployment, as well as [in a few other situations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#when-does-the-release-command-run).

### `prisma generate`

`npx prisma generate` should not be part of your release process. It must be run in your *development environment*, and the files it generates need to be committed. By the time your code reaches Heroku, this command should have no more work to do.

Heroku dynos use an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any files created or modified on Heroku will be lost each time the dyno restarts. This happens frequently, at least once per day.

---

¹Note that you've defined the same process type, `run`, twice. Only one command can be assigned to any given process type, so only one of the commands you've declared will actually run this way.